# Compensating for margin: 0 auto in IE

Tags: css

You can see the live version here: http://steffiwilson.com/test.

IE9 is not centering the content block. (I am pretty sure that older versions of IE aren't working either, but I can't say for sure.) I've made sure that there's a doctype and that my code is valid. I applied

```
text-align: center;
```

to the parent elements of the content block, but it's not working. So then I thought maybe I'd have IE go to a js file that would override it by giving it an absolute position, but I determined by alert statements that it's not getting through the third line here.

```
screenwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
sidespace = ((screenwidth - 700)/2) + "px";
document.getElementById("content").style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById("content").style.left = sidespace;
```

Any ideas? I'm willing to do anything that works -- CSS or Javascript. I'm wondering if the code for my stickyfooter is causing the issues.

Here are relevant portions of my CSS:

```
* {
margin:0;
  padding:0;
} 

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #c1e9e9;
  background-image: url('images/background.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: center;
  min-width: 750px;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#main {
  overflow:auto;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  width:700px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:left;
  padding:15px;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -150px; 
  height: 150px;
  clear:both;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('images/dog.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  /*"sticky footer" design credit to www.cssstickyfooter.com*/
} 


/*Opera Fix for sticky footer */
  body:before {
  content:"";
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  width:0;
  margin-top:-32767px;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#wrap` gets misaligned, so aligning `#content` or `#main` won't work. Change your rule for `#wrap` to

```
#wrap {
  margin:0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

and it will work in IE.

**EDIT**: `#wrap` is misaligned because you set its display property to `display:table` in a conditional comment. As far as I can see you don't want to use this in IE6,8,9 (`<!--[if !IE 7]>`), but in IE<7 (`<!--[if lt IE 7]>`). So change this comment or drop it.

Comment: That comment is part of the stickyfooter code. Adding the margin: 0 auto to #wrap worked, although the white backdrop and green bar that are part of the navigation tabs aren't going across the whole page in IE like in Firefox.